# Value is only sliced every two times despite running every time

Tags: angular

I'm writing a component that should only allow certain number formats, it works great except for one thing, it slices the value every time but only updates the view every two times. So if I write it in this sequence:

A
B
C
D

I end up with BD.

I can't understand what is happening here.

This is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  templateUrl: 'my-input.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-input.css'],
  inputs: [
    'model',
    'pattern'
  ],
  host: {
    '(input)': 'isNum($event.target.value)'
  },
  providers: [
    RegexService
  ]
})

export class FormNumberInputComponent {
  @Input() model: number;
  @Output('modelChange') onModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _regexes: RegexService) {}

  isNum(value) {

    this.isInvalid = !this._regexes.test(this.pattern || 'integer', value);

    if (!this.isInvalid) {
      this.onModelChange.emit(value);
    }
    else {

      value = value.slice(0, -1);

      // This also doesn't work, gives the same result
      value = value.substring(0, -1);

      this.onModelChange.emit(value);
    }
  }
}
```

And the simple template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model">
```

Using it from parent component like this:

```
<my-input [(model)]="myModel1"></my-input>
```

Comment: I noticed you are using `slice` in the code, but in your question you say you are `splicing`. This is the issue I think, because slice returns a whole new array instead of changing it in-place like `splice` does.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Ah sorry that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. I will try substring as splice doesn't work on strings.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Same result with substring.

Comment: Can you show your RegexService and where do you pass pattern input?

Comment: @yurzui The RegexService isn't where the problem lies so I won't include it in the question as it's quite huge, and I don't pass a pattern as it defaults to integer if a pattern isn't given.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought it was an array. I see what are you doing now. I have created a simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OHKvMrDRprz0GoTHaFgq?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.onModelChange.emit(new String(value));
```

[image]

Here is corresponding plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/2KqCGggSDOdXhjiJEw68?p=preview

I would write instead of component validation custom pipe for that: https://plnkr.co/edit/xCvnJ9682lV0Z1sBcK68?p=preview

Maybe it will be interesting also http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: Sick, you just cut my 20 liner into 1 line. Facing a problem with negative values and separators such as dots, commas and hyphens though since it will count 0. as invalid before you can write 0.1 for example. Any ideas how to implement this into your answer?

Comment: What does that image mean?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I've update plunker for your first question

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Image explains why 'new String' fires updating changes. This way data will become immutable

Comment: Mate you're a legend, I could kiss you. THANK YOU.